# How to add more than one information to the same ID?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am creating a code that works with database, and would like to know how to add more than one information to the same ID.

It is for a student's note control code.

```
def add_series(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('obje_bd.db')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        id_ = self.ids.txt_id.text.encode('utf-8')
        series = self.ids.txt_series_professor.text.encode('utf-8')
        # alterando os dados da tabela
        cursor.execute("""
              # would like to put all series in the same ID.
              INSERT INTO lista_professores WHERE id = ?, series = ?""")

        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```

Comment: Could you provide more of your source and database structure, at least for this table?

Comment: Of course, I'm sorry, follow the columns.

ID | Name | series |
0   | Jonh  |    1
                      2
                      3
I would like to have more than one data in this column related to John's ID.

Answer (score 2):

Typically you wouldn't directly, that is if the *"more information"* is a variable amount of information per id.

For example assume that a Student (the assumption is that a student's row has an **id**) has x number of notes.

You would not have x columns (as you would forever be adding new columns).

It would prove clumsy to place all the notes into single column with a separator e.g something like 'Hello this is my first note','Thankyou this is my second note' and so on.

- e.g. if a comma separates data how do you cope with commas in the notes.
- how do you split the data, say to find note 3?

What you would typically do is **normalise** the data and have a table for the notes, each note being an individual row. There would be a column in the notes table that **relates** the note to the respective student.
- SQLite is a **relational** database and handles relationships pretty well.

## Example

Consider the following, where instead of a Student having x number of data (notes) in the Student table another table for the notes exists and each note contains a column for relating the note to the student :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Student;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Note;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Student (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Note(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, studentReference INTEGER, note TEXT);

INSERT INTO Student (name) VALUES ('Fred'),('Mary'),('Anne'); -- ids will be 1 2 and 3 

INSERT INTO Note (studentReference,note) VALUES
    (1,'My Note 1'),
    (3,'My Note 1'),
    (3,'My Note 2'),
    (2,'My Note 1'),
    (3,'My Note 3'),
    (2,'My Note 2'),
    (2,'My Note 3'),
    (1,'My Note 2'),
    (1,'My Note 3'),
    (1,'My Note 4'),
    (1,'My Note 5'),
    (3,'My Note 4');

    SELECT * FROM Student; -- The Student table
    SELECT * FROM Note; -- The Note table
    -- Get the Notes with the Student (both have the same result)
    SELECT name, note FROM Note JOIN Student ON Student.id = Note.studentReference ORDER BY Student.name;
    SELECT name, note FROM Student JOIN  Note ON Student.id = Note.studentReference ORDER BY Student.name;
    -- Get the number of notes and all the notes concatenated as a CSV per student
    SELECT student.name,count(), group_concat(note) FROM student JOIN Note ON Student.id = Note.studentReference GROUP BY student.id;
```

## Results

### 1 The Student Table

[image]

### 2 The Notes Table

[image]

### 3 and 4 Student and Notes

[image]

### 5 Number of notes and the notes as a CSV per student

[image]

Comment: Ok, thank you, I believe it works with sqlite3 as well. right?

Comment: @FernandoFosterHomohabilis, yes, SQlite3 was used for the above.